Connection String with Multisbunetfailover=true fails. States mirrored SQL Server Instance not supported
I have two SQL servers configured with an availability group. The configurations uses a dnn for it's listener. Connection tests to the configured port are successful.
When we try to make a connection with multisubnetfailover=true in the connection string, we get the following error message:

Connecting to a mirrored SQL Server instance using the multiSubnetFailover connection property is not supported.

This system has never been configured with a mirror. I've ran
SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASE_MIRRORING
The results of the command was NULL. Any suggestions what I can check to resolve this?

what sql server driver are you using? can you share the full connection string?

Needed to turn on readable secondary on the availability group.
